# Save custom searches for quick access

Tags: feature-request, tags, usability, search

Twitter has a nice feature to save searches so you can quickly access them quickly in the sidebar.

It would be nice to have something like that for SO/MSO/SU/SF.

Instead of having to type in my search, like

```
[discussion feature-request only-awesome-features]
```

in the search box every time, I could save them as a search preset and access them in my prefs in a tab called "Favorite searches" or something like that.

Even better, the saved searches would be available in the site's sidebar, e.g. under related tags.

**EDIT:**
I know, the search is not the best, but searching for certain **tags** or **groups of tags** (in the syntax: [tag1 tag2 tag3]) actually works ok, IMO. That's what I want to use it for, searching for certain groups of tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can always bookmark the search page in your browser.

... and by the way, *do you **really** use SO search?* Everyone knows it sucks.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Bookmarking basically works, but is only accessible from the machine bookmarked on, unless I use del.icio.us or something.

Comment: SO's search works reasonably well for tags, or other special-purpose operators (`user:`, etc.). But yeah, a saved keyword search sounds about pointless.